# Kotlin My app android emulator and my decive working but signed or debug apk not working

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, emulation, signed

My application works on the android emulator and when I connect my mobile phone, but when I install it on another phone as both debug and release apk, I get an error "Unfortunately, the application has stopped" without opening the application.
Please Help me.. Thanks
(Google Translate)

application link: https://github.com/erdemselvi/Namazvakitleri.git

Proguard

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
# -keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile


-keep class android.Manifest
-keep class android.support.v4.app.RemoteActionCompatParcelizer
```

logcat while the emulator is running

```
2021-04-20 01:16:41.228 22379-22572/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2021-04-20 01:16:41.384 22379-22572/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2021-04-20 01:16:41.501 22379-22379/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/endate: Tue Apr 20 04:02:00 GMT 2021
2021-04-20 01:16:41.501 22379-22379/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/entime: 20.04.2021, 04:02:00
2021-04-20 01:16:42.497 22379-22559/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/chromium: [ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.
2021-04-20 01:16:42.557 22379-22559/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/chromium: [ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.
2021-04-20 01:16:43.455 22379-22675/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2021-04-20 01:16:43.458 22379-22675/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2021-04-20 01:16:43.461 22379-22675/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Inappropriate ioctl for device
2021-04-20 01:16:43.462 22379-22675/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2021-04-20 01:16:43.472 22379-22679/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2021-04-20 01:16:43.524 22379-22685/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/EGL_emulation: eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
2021-04-20 01:16:43.524 22379-22685/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/EGL_emulation: tid 22685: eglQueryContext(2019): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2021-04-20 01:16:43.525 22379-22682/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/ACodec: [OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010
2021-04-20 01:16:44.436 22379-22379/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/Reklam: Reklam yüklendi
2021-04-20 01:17:53.465 22379-22559/com.erdemselvi.namazvakitleri E/chromium: [ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.
```

Build - while the emulator is running

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleRelease] in project F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri


> Configure project :app
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

> Task :clean
> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesRelease
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources
> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsRelease
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets
> Task :app:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :app:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :app:validateSigningRelease
> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesRelease
> Task :app:processReleaseResources

> Task :app:compileReleaseKotlin
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/msiselvi/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ce27050e6167858fff01061a0dd62875/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.72.jar (version 1.3)
    C:/Users/msiselvi/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/0fa7610dd6abdd728768892c9596c6f2/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.4.32.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/msiselvi/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/177e0fffef8f7f46911a72645f607e8d/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.32.jar (version 1.4)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (300, 33): 'getRunningServices(Int): (Mutable)List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo!>!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (583, 20): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (587, 29): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (589, 29): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (593, 27): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (597, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (600, 26): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (604, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (606, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (609, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (613, 26): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (615, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (617, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (620, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (625, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (627, 26): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (629, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (631, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (634, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (639, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (641, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (643, 26): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (645, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (648, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (653, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (655, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (657, 26): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (659, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected
w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\GunlukVakitActivity.kt: (662, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected

> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :app:compileReleaseSources
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease
> Task :app:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :app:multiDexListRelease
> Task :app:mergeDexRelease
> Task :app:packageRelease
> Task :app:assembleRelease

BU�LD SUCCESSFUL in 16s
35 actionable tasks: 35 executed

Build Analyzer results available
```

It works fine on the emulator.
I uploaded it to the play console. The application installs on the phone but does not open at all and there is a stopped error.

Comment: It's a proguard issue, if you attach your proguard rules + Exception you see in logcat, we might be able to help

Comment: I added everything I can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled Android studio. I deleted the build folders in the project. After doing clean and rebuild, it improved interestingly.